# Problem regarding signup form submission data not being received in the backend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am following a video course for creation of an Online exam portal using Angular for frontend and Springboot for backend along with MySQl for DB. We have been shown how to create the backend code for adding a new user and have tested that it is indeed working through the Postman app. However while trying to do the same through the frontend signup form I am facing this issue :-

[Error shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UontL.png)

[Here's the same POST request being sent through Postman app which works and updates the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM0m9.png)

[Users Table updated successfully through sending the request using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atd9y.png)

[My frontend file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1GxK.png)

**My "signup.component.ts" file:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService:UserService){}

  public user={
    username:'',
    password:'',
    firstname:'',
    lastname:'',
    email:'',
    mobile:''
  }

  ngOnInit():void{}

  formSubmit(){
    
    console.log(this.user);
    if(this.user.username == '' || this.user.username == null){
      alert('User Name Field cannot be blank!');
      return;
    }

    //addUser:UserService
    
      this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
        {
          next: (data) => console.log(data),
          error: (err) => console.log(err),
          complete: () => console.log("completed")
        });

  }

}
```

**My "helper.ts" file :-**

```
 let baseUrl="http//:localhost:8080"
 export default baseUrl
```

**My "user.service.ts" file :-**

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

public addUser (user:any){
  return this.http.post('${baseUrl}/user/',user);
}

}
```

[Backend file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE0Xv.png)

**My "UserController.java" file :-**

```
package com.exam.controller;

import com.exam.entity.Role;
import com.exam.entity.User;
import com.exam.entity.UserRole;
import com.exam.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //create user
    @PostMapping("/")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {

        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleID(191001001105L); //Default role id set
        role.setRoleName("NORMAL");

        UserRole userRole= new UserRole();
        userRole.setUser(user);
        userRole.setRole(role);

        Set<UserRole> roles= new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(userRole);

        return this.userService.createUser(user,roles);
    }

    //get user by username
    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("username") String username){
        return this.userService.getUser(username);
    }

    //delete user by Id
    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId){
        this.userService.deleteUser(userId);
    }

}
```

My Apache Tomcat Server is running on port 8080 while the Angular Development Server is running on 4200.

Any help regarding this issue will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're posting to is incorrect, as is evident from the console error. It looks like you where trying to use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but used the wrong type of quotes.

Correct your `addUser()` function as follows to correctly interpolate the `baseUrl`:

```
public addUser(user: any) {
  return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/user/`, user);
}
```

You'll also need to import the `baseUrl` variable from your `helper.ts` file. Also note that there's a typo in your `baseUrl`: it should be `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http//:localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I changed the quotes and now getting this: Error: src/app/services/user.service.ts:13:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'baseUrl'.

Comment: Because you're not importing it from your `helper.ts` file.

Comment: `import baseUrl from './helper';` solved that problem however still getting this error `POST http://localhost:4200/http//:localhost:8080/user/ 404 (Not Found)` . For whatever reason it seems to be appending 'http://localhost:4200/' infront of the url.

Comment: Because your `baseUrl` should be `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http//:localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thank you that worked  out perfectly. Now I feel a bit stupid for not noticing that previously.

Comment: It happens. As long as you provide all the relevant details in the question and subsequent comments (like you did, +1), we get to a solution eventually :)